# How to remove wood filler to get to the screws

Tags: wood, wood-filler

I have a wobbly table leg and so I want to get to the screws that are meant to be hold the leg in place. How do I get to the screw heads that are covered in wood filler (or maybe wood glue).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, make sure there aren't nuts and washers on the other side of that wobbly leg that you could just tighten up.

Drill a small hole in the filler/glue down to the screw and then cut away the rest with a utility knife. If you have a Dremel or other spin tool, use a bottoming bit and clean out the area.

You might find that the screw holes were just worn bigger. In that case, you might want to drill right through the leg and get some longer bolts, washers and nuts and re assemble rather than just tightening them up or getting larger screws. That way you won't run into the wobbly leg again.

Comment: Why bother to remove the existing fasteners? Just drill two or more holes in each joint and add bolts/washers/nuts as @JACK suggests

Comment: That worked @JACK. I drilled and cut to the screw, and then removed it. And replaced with a not-twisted-and-bent screw. Also turned the leg around because the holes had stretched. Thanks.